# What is the difference between these 2 FFMPEG commands?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video

I am trying to take 5 static images named (1,2,3,4 and 5.jpg) and turn them in a 25 second video with each image being 5 seconds long.

```
ffmpeg -y -r 25 -loop 1 -t 5 -i 1.jpg -s 1080x1920 video1.mp4
ffmpeg -y -r 25 -loop 1 -t 5 -i 2.jpg -s 1080x1920 video2.mp4
ffmpeg -y -r 25 -loop 1 -t 5 -i 3.jpg -s 1080x1920 video3.mp4
ffmpeg -y -r 25 -loop 1 -t 5 -i 4.jpg -s 1080x1920 video4.mp4
ffmpeg -y -r 25 -loop 1 -t 5 -i 5.jpg -s 1080x1920 video5.mp4
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -c copy output.mp4
(where files is the list of video1-5.mp4)
```

vs

```
ffmpeg -y -r 25 -loop 1 -t 5 -i %d.jpg -s 1080x1920 video.mp4
```

The second command took so long, I got bored of waiting for it to complete, but the first command completes in seconds. There are no additional files with would match `%d.jpg` so it cant be bringing extra files in.

In my head, these commands do the same thing so its likely a lack of understanding.
Is it that the second command is reencoding when it comes to joining the videos which is taking a long time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second command seems wrong you inform -t 5 but that would be the total time of the sequence not for each image, if you would like to set the time for each image you would have to use something like: -r 1/5 or set the duration inside the list file:

```
file '1.jpg'
duration 5
file '2.jpg'
duration 5
file '3.jpg'
duration 5
```

Since your images seem to be sequenced you could use something like this:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1/5 -i "%d.jpg" -vf "scale=1920:-2:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease" -c mjpeg -y -r 3 output.mp4
```

The command really shouldn't take long unless you have a really big amount of images...